# Finding grids in binary matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, binary

I am given a binary matrix in Matlab and I am interested in finding grid structures in this binary matrix.

For example, consider this "chessboard" binary matrix:

```
X = zeros(11,20);
indeces = 1:2:220;
X(indeces) = 1;
imshow(X);
```

In this case the result would be two subgrids given by

```
x = 1:1:20;
y = 1:1:11;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

% First subgrid
X1 = ( mod(X - 1,2) == 0 & mod(Y - 1,2) == 0);
imshow(X1)

% Second subgrid
X2 = (mod(X,2) == 0 & mod(Y,2) == 0);
imshow(X2)
```

Of course, this is an easy example, usually `X` would be a lot less regular. I could provide a maximum step size for the grid to find.

EDIT: To make this precise: A **grid G** is a binary matrix defined by the following parameters - the total size `size(G)`, an upper left corner `[x0,y0]`, a spacing `s` between the grid's points and the number of points in horizontal and vertical direction, respectively, `numX, numY`. Here is one possibility to construct a grid from these parameters:

```
function G = createGrid(totalSize,upperLeft,stepSize,numX,numY)

x = 1:totalSize(2);
y = 1:totalSize(1);

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

G = (mod(X - upperLeft(1),stepSize) == 0 & ...
    mod(Y - upperLeft(2),stepSize) == 0 & ...
   (X - upperLeft(1) + 1 > 0) & ...
   (X < upperLeft(1) + stepSize * (numX - 1) + 1) & ...
   (Y - upperLeft(2) + 1 > 0) & ... 
   (Y < upperLeft(2)  + stepSize * (numY - 1) + 1));
```

A **subgrid** `G` of a binary matrix `M` is a grid such that `sum(~(M(G)==1)) = 0`. Note that in particular grids can be subgrids of other grids.

A subgrid `G` of a binary matrix `M` is called **maximal** if the following holds: If `G` is a subgrid of another grid `G2` that is not identical to `G`, then `G2` is not a subgrid of `M`. In other words - I can't make it any bigger.

So the precise formulation of my question is: How can I find all maximal subgrids of a given binary matrix `M`?

Are there ready-made algorithms available for this problem? What would be approaches if not? Placing seeds across the binary matrix and trying to extend them to grids as far as possible?

Comment: Let's go with the example you have defined.  How **do you know** that there are two subgrids?  What is your definition of a subgrid?  From here it seems quite ambiguous.  Someone could say that you can extract out a subgrid by looking at those values that have the same intensity.  Other people can say that the way the values have been defined follow a pattern, and so you extract out locations that correspond to this pattern. Therefore, **what is your definition of a subgrid?**  Including a more non-regular example and how you extracted those subgrids would be beneficial for understanding.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you for your comment. I tried to make my question more precise. Let me know if I'm still unclear.